# How to explain double slit fringes experiment using the fact that light is electromagnetic in nature?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, huygens-principle

Huygens principle explains the double slit fringes experiment, by assuming that each gap (or slit) behaves as an individual light source, but according to EM (electromagnetic) theory, we can't assume that for an explanation. EM waves should just pass through the gap since there is nothing in the gap, and so there will not be fringes. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand exactly what it is you're confused about. Can you please clarify? It's true that waves pass through the gap, and it's also true that Huygen's principle will allow you to calculate the correct fringe patterns (in nonrelativistic wave mechanics and Maxwell's equations).

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct in your question, material waves and light waves are very different. The Huygens math does however coincide with the more advanced EM theories when you divide the single slit into half wavelength separate sources.  And the Huygens explanation is easy to teach and test for schools. But photons do not interact or cancel each other, that would be a violation of conservation of energy. Feynman path integral offers a good explanation for the pattern  .... try to avoid the word "interference".

Comment: Taking a 4th year quantum optics course is where you start to see the light.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to solve the Maxwell equations with the appropriate boundary conditions on the screen and the slits - this is also to say that thinking in terms of plane waves passing through a slit is misleading, since such waves extend to infinity in all directions.

Huygens-Fresnel approch is actually an approximate way of solving the Maxwell equations, derived from [Kirchhoff diffraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_diffraction_formula), which in turn follows from the [Kirchhoff integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff_integral_theorem), which is exact.

In quantum mechanics the same ideas are expressed in terms of Green's functions and path integrals.

Comment: I think it's a bit pedantic to call it an approximation. The wave equation is linear, and this is extended to the class of generalised distributions. A complete (and not overcomplete) boundary surface for the first-order wave equation (Maxwell's equations) is given by an expression for the EM fields $\psi(\vec x, t=0)$ at a fixed time-slice. This initial condition may then be decomposed into dirac-delta distributions and yield the entire EM field for all time using Green's functions $K$, per $\psi(\vec x, t) = \int \mathrm d x' K(\vec x' \vec x, t) \psi(\vec x', 0)$.

Comment: Only objection I can see is that Huygen's principle does not exactly use a constant time slice.

Comment: @Myridium I think the disagreement is about the terminology - what one calls *Huygens principle*. The view expressed above is in agreement with the Feynmann quote given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle#Generalized_Huygens'_principle

Comment: I think the second-order time derivative comes in as a consequence of considering the exact expression for relativistic energy, i.e. $E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$. So, in non-relativistic mechanics, the equation is linear and per my comment (and Feynmann's quote) the Huygens-Fresnel formula is correct.

My point really is that the OP is not asking about relativity and probably does not care at this stage. Their question is entirely different, and for non-relativistic purposes it's actually correct to use Huygen's principle, so we should help the OP understand why, rather than saying it's wrong.

Comment: @Myridium the question is actually about optics. Still, I don't really see any disagreement here. If you want to propose different phrasing, I have nothing against adjusting my answer.